# DataBase independent way of setting time fractions?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, columndefinition

How can I define column data type for datetime to store time fractions independently from DB platform?
Now I am using code like that:

```
@Column(name = "DATE_TIME", columnDefinition = "datetime(3) NOT NULL")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateTime;
```

That is for MySQL over v.5 ("datetime(3) NOT NULL").
p.s. Using java.util.Date

Comment: I would expect the JPA provider to handle that for you, so that milliseconds are stored. If it isn't then raise an issue on your JPA provider, saying what Java type (that does support milliseconds) is losing precision due to their choice of datastore type.

Comment: millis not stored by default (checked!). That's why I've used "columnDefinition".

Comment: The ANSI SQL datatype would be `TIMESTAMP` - but that means something different in different DBMS. The best way I know is to use something like Liquibase and do **not** let your obfuscation layer (aka ORM) create the tables

Comment: Yes I know you used columnDefinition for that purpose. My point is that the JPA provider should do it for you! That is the only way you will truly get DB independence (without having to have an orm.xml for each datastore)